# Fast and accurate double precision implementation of incomplete gamma function

Tags: efficiency, accuracy, special-functions

What is the state of the art way of implementing double precision special functions? I need the following integral:
$$
    F_m(t) = \int_0^1 u^{2m} e^{-tu^2} d u
        = {\gamma(m+{1\over 2}, t)\over 2 t^{m+{1\over 2}}}
$$
for $m=0, 1, 2, ...$ and $t>0$, which can be written in terms of the lower incomplete gamma function. Here is my Fortran and C implementation:

https://gist.github.com/3764427

which uses series expansion, sums up the terms until the given accuracy, and then uses recursion relations to efficiently obtain values for lower $m$. I tested it well and I get 1e-15 accuracy for all values of parameters that I need, see the Fortran version's comments for details.

Is there a better way to implement it? Here is a gamma function implementation in gfortran:

https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libgfortran/intrinsics/c99_functions.c#L1781

it is using rational function approximation instead of summing up some infinite series that I am doing. I think that's a better approach, because one should obtain uniform accuracy. Is there some canonical way to approach these things, or does one have to figure out a special algorithm for each special function?

**Update 1**:

Based on the comments, here is the implementation using SLATEC:

https://gist.github.com/3767621

it reproduces values from my own function, roughly on the level of 1e-15 accuracy. However, I noticed a problem that for t=1e-6 and m=50, the $t^{m+{1\over2}}$ term gets equal to 1e-303 and for higher "m" it simply starts giving incorrect answers. My function doesn't have this problem, because I use a series expansion/recurrence relations directly for $F_m$. Here is an example of a correct value:

$F_{100}$`(1e-6)=4.97511945200351715E-003`,

but I can't get this using SLATEC because the denominator blows up. As you can see, the actual value of $F_m$ is nice and small.

**Update 2**:

To avoid the above problem, one can use the function `dgamit` (Tricomi's incomplete Gamma function), then `F(m, t) = dgamit(m+0.5_dp, t) * gamma(m+0.5_dp) / 2`, so there is no problem with $t$ anymore, but unfortunately the `gamma(m+0.5_dp)` blows up for $m\approx 172$. This however might be high enough $m$ for my purposes.

Comment: Why code your own function? GSL, cephes, and SLATEC all implement it.

Comment: I've updated the question why I don't use SLATEC.

Comment: @OndřejČertík You have apperantly discovered a bug! Upvoted your question!

Comment: Ali --- it's not a bug in SLATEC, but in the fact, that I actually need to divide the $\gamma(z, x)$ by $t^{m+{1\over2}}$ in order to obtain a value for $F_m(t)$. So the numerical method that works for $\gamma(z, x)$ might not work so well for $F_m(t)$.

Comment: @OndřejČertík OK, sorry, my mistake, I didn't check your code before making my comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The integral in question is also known as the Boys function, after the British chemist Samuel Francis Boys who introduced its use in the early 1950s. A few years ago, I needed to compute this function in double precision, as fast as possible but accurately. I managed to achieve a relative error on the order of $10^{-15}$ across the entire input domain.

It is generally advantageous to use different approximations for small and large arguments, where the optimal switch-over between "large" and "small" is best determined experimentally, and is in general a function of $m$. For my code, I defined "small" arguments as those satisfying condition $a \le m + 1{1\over 2}$.

For large arguments, I compute

$$\mathrm{F}_m(a) = {1\over 2}\gamma\left(m + {1\over 2}, a\right) \times p \times p, \space \space p = a^{-{1\over 2}\left(m+ {1\over 2}\right)}$$

This order of operations avoids premature underflow. As we need only the lower incomplete gamma function of half-integer orders here rather than a fully general lower incomplete gamma function, it is advantageous from a performance perspective to compute

$$\gamma \left(m + {1\over 2}, a\right) = \Gamma \left(m + {1\over 2}\right) - \Gamma\left(m + {1\over 2}, a\right)$$

using tabulated values of $\Gamma \left(m + {1\over 2}\right)$ and computing $\Gamma\left(m + {1\over 2}, a\right)$ according to
[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724068/expressing-upper-incomplete-gamma-function-of-half-integer-order-in-terms-of-gam), while carefully avoiding the issue of subtractive cancellation through use of a fused multiply-add operation. A potential further optimization is to observe that for sufficiently large $a$, $\gamma \left(m + {1\over 2}, a\right) = \Gamma \left(m + {1\over 2}\right)$ to within a given floating-point precision.

For small arguments, I started with a series expansion for the lower incomplete gamma function from

*A. Erdelyi, W. Magnus, F. Oberhettinger, and F.G. Tricomi, "Higher 
Transcendental Functions, Vol. 2". New York, NY: McGraw-Hill 1953*

and modified it to compute the Boys function $\mathrm{F}_{m}(a)$ as follows (truncating the series when the term is sufficiently small for a given precision):

$$\mathrm{F}_{m}(a) = {1\over 2}\frac{1}{m + {1\over 2}}\exp(-a)\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n}}{(1 + m + {1\over 2}) \times\space  ...\space \times (n + m + {1\over 2})}\right)$$

There are also interesting and potentially important special cases for low orders of the Boys function, particularly $m = 0, 1, 2, 3$. First, we have $\mathrm{F}_{0}(a) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4a}}\mathrm{erf}\left(\sqrt{a}\right)$, where $\mathrm{erf}$ is the error function provided in Fortran 2008 as the elemental function `ERF` and in C/C++ as the standard library functions `erf` and `erff`.

For fast computation when $m = 1, 2, 3$, I use custom minimax polynomial approximations for small arguments, say $a \lt {2{1\over 2}}$, and forward recursion $\mathrm{F}_{m}(a) = \frac{1}{2a}\left(\left(2m-1\right)\mathrm{F}_{m-1}(a) - \exp(-a)\right)$, for large ones, where issues with subtractive cancellation in the latter are mitigated by the use of fused multiply-add operations.

Where function values have to be computed for a given $a$ across multiple orders $m$, one would want to compute the function value for the highest value of $m$ directly, i.e. as discussed above, then use the numerically stable backward recursion $\mathrm{F}_{m-1} = \frac{1}{2m-1} \left(2a \space \mathrm{F}_{m}(a) + \exp\left(-a\right)\right)$ to compute all the other function values.

Comment: Thanks @njuffa for the great answer. If you make your code for this open source, I think it would be very useful to lots of people.

Comment: Currently, a CUDA implementation of the algorithm described is available for free download from [NVIDIA's developer website](https://developer.nvidia.com/) (requires free registration as a CUDA developer, approval usually within one business day). The code is under a BSD license, which should be compatible with just about any kind of project.

Answer (score 5):

You might take a look at [Numerical Methods for Special Functions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898716349) by 
Amparo Gil, Javier Segura, and Nico M. Temme.

Comment: This is a great book, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4):

I'd take a look at Abramowicz & Stegun's book, or the newer revision that NIST has published a couple of years ago and that's available online I believe. They also discuss ways to implement things in a stable way.

Comment: I was using this: http://dlmf.nist.gov/8, when implementing it, but that's probably another resource. The chapter 5 in Numerical Recipes also has interesting info, but only applicable to functions of one variable.

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything much more recent than their 2001 reference; SLATEC will be older than that.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be *state-of-the-art* but [SLATEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLATEC) at Netlib offers "1400 general purpose mathematical and statistical routines." The incomplete Gamma is available under the [special functions here](http://www.netlib.org/slatec/fnlib/).

Implementing such functions is time consuming and error prone so I wouldn't do it myself unless absolutely necessary. SLATEC has been around for quite a while now and is widely used, at least based on the [download counts](http://www.netlib.org/master_counts2.html), so I would expect the implementation to be mature.